# Calculate Time that two TimeSlots have in Common

Tags: java, time

I need to calculate the time two timeslots have in common. I wanted to know if there's a efficient way to calculate this. I know that saving the hours in int isn't the best way to do it. Can someone suggest me a new way to save it and calculate it?

I need to calculate the duration during which two available timeslots are overlapping. For example, if I have a first available timeslot that is from 10:00 to 13:00 on Thursday and another one from 12:00 to 14:00 on Thursday, we can calculate how much time both are avalaible.

```
public class TimeSlot implements Cloneable {

    int day;
    int hourStart;
    int hourEnd;
    int minutesStart;
    int minutesEnd;
    int id;

    public TimeSlot(int day, int hourStart, int hourEnd, int minutesStart, int minutesEnd) {
        this.day = day;
        this.hourStart = hourStart;
        this.hourEnd = hourEnd;
        this.minutesStart = minutesStart;
        this.minutesEnd = minutesEnd;
        this.id = AutoIDGenerator.getAutoIdTimeSlot();

    }

    @Override
    protected TimeSlot clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (TimeSlot) super.clone();
    }

    public boolean isTheSameDay(TimeSlot t) {
        if (this.getDay() == t.getDay()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param t
     * @return si l'heure fournie est après this timeslot
     */
    public boolean isAfter(TimeSlot t) {
        if (this.isTheSameDay(t)) {
            if (this.getHourEnd() > t.getHourStart()) {
                return true;
            } else if (this.getHourEnd() == t.getHourStart() && this.getMinutesEnd() > t.getMinutesStart()) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param t
     * @return si l'heure fournie est avant this timeslot
     */
    public boolean isBefore(TimeSlot t) {
        if (this.isTheSameDay(t)) {
            if (this.getHourStart() > t.getHourEnd()) {
                return true;
            } else if ((this.getHourStart() == t.getHourEnd()) && (this.getMinutesStart() > t.getMinutesEnd())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isCompatible(TimeSlot t) {
        if (!(isBefore(t)) && !(isAfter(t))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with to have in common??

Comment: i need to calculate the duration during which Two timeslots are overlapping. For example, if i have a first Timeslot that is from 10 o'clock to 13 o'clock on thursday and another one that is from 12 o'clock to 2 oclock on thursday, we can calculate how much time we are both avalaible.That,s what i need to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use joda time, it has an [Interval class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) with [an `overlap` method](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap(org.joda.time.ReadableInterval)) that does exactly what you need.

Second best solution would be to use a proper date representation, either with a `Date` if you use Java 7 or earlier or with an `Instant` if you use Java 8.

With Java 8, your class could look like:

```
class Timeslot {
  Instant start, end;

  Duration overlap(Timeslot other) {
    long startOverlap = Math.max(this.start.toEpochMilli(), other.start.toEpochMilli());
    long endOverlap = Math.min(this.end.toEpochMilli(), other.end.toEpochMilli());
    if (endOverlap <= startOverlap) return Duration.ofMillis(0); //or a negative duration?
    else return Duration.ofMillis(endOverlap - startOverlap);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and confortable way to solve this is using dates,
you need to define 4 dates, they are:
event A begin time, event A end time, event B begin time, event B end time,

then check if there are overlapings in those dates

if so calculate how much (in milliseconds looks good) and finally format that difference in millisecods to a HH:mm:ss format

## Example:

```
long millis = 0;
        
Date eventOneBegin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2016-4-06 06:00:00");
Date eventOneEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2016-4-06 09:00:00");
 Date eventTwoBegin = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2016-4-06 08:00:00");
 Date eventTwoEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2016-4-06 11:00:00");

 if (eventOneEnd.getTime()>eventTwoBegin.getTime()) {
    System.out.println("there is a overlap time");
    millis = eventOneEnd.getTime()-eventTwoBegin.getTime();
}else{
    System.out.println("there is NO overlap time....");
}
 String lapse=String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -  
        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), // The change is in this line
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));   
 System.out.println("Time overlap is: "+lapse);
```

---

this example generates this

> Time overlap is: 01:00:00

between the 2 event defined

I hope I got the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the java.util.Calendar [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Your time slot can be defined with 2 Calendar values for start and end time.
You can operate than with the milliseconds of the calendar times (use the method getTimeInMillis()).

Using java.util.Calendar for the time slots, you can have solution for any precision (day, hour, minute...)